# AppInsight Log errors not showing issue

Tags: azure, .net-core, appinsights

I have configured Azure app insight to my web application.  I have added code as below.

```
  catch (Exception serverEx)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError("hello world");
                        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted, serverEx.Message);
                    }
```

This is visible in traces.

[image]

This is an exception So I need to load it in exceptions. This is my query.

```
let start=datetime("2022-02-24T14:23:00.000Z");
let end=datetime("2022-02-25T14:23:00.000Z");
let timeGrain=5m;
let dataset=exceptions 
| where timestamp > start and timestamp < end
| where client_Type == "Browser"
;
dataset
```

This query not getting any result. Even I type Exceptions its not getting any result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution myself. If this is incorrect please correct me.

traces
| where severityLevel == 3

[image]